# PDO class with bind function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new in PDO and i found this tutorial how to write PDO php class:
http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/

This class includes bind function:

```
public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
    if (is_null($type)) {
        switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
    }

    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}
```

When i use it my code looks like:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
    //$blang (browser language)
    $blangtmp = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']; 
    $blangtmp = str_replace( ' ', '', $blangtmp );
    $blangtmp = explode( ",", $blangtmp );
    $blang = $blangtmp[0];

    $blang = "'%$blang'";

    $database = new Database();
    $database->query('SELECT id_language FROM `my_table` WHERE language_locale LIKE :blang ;');
    $database->bind(':blang', $blang);
    $idlang = $database->execute(); 

    $database = null;

    echo $idlang;

}
```

When i echo $idlang i have always 1 ...

It looks like binding not working at all...
I get no error and no warnings.

Any idea how to get proper idlang value?

Comment: i would suggest don't reinvent the wheel, there are plenty of good PDO libraries which can help, try [notORM](http://www.notorm.com/) its simple and fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `$database->execute();`  returns true , you will need to fetch the data

```
$success = $database->execute(); 
if(!success){
   die('failed');
}      
$records = $database->resultset();

foreach($records as $record){
  $id_lang = $record['id_language'];
  echo $id_lang;
}
```

or if you only expect one result then use `single()`

That said I don't see any benefit in rolling your own PDO Class, it will just limit you.

Even the tutorial author agrees with that:

> Whilst the class we looked
>   at is great for getting started with PDO quickly, it does have some
>   restrictions if you want to do more complicated things than simple
>   selects, inserts, updates and deletes.
>   I think it is also far more beneficial to know exactly what is going
>   on under the hood of your code. By knowing exactly how something works
>   you will gain a much deeper sense of understanding and you will be
>   able to troubleshoot and advance your code when the time comes.

But I don't judge so just remember that it's better not to wrap PDO which is already wrapper class.

Comment: Thanks for answer!
I didn't know how to start and set the PDO_MYSQL DSN availeable for whole project so this PDO class whose best solution for me...

Still dont know what is best practise to set DSN and pass and user only once.

Answer (score 0):

From your link:

```
public function execute(){
    return $this->stmt->execute();
}
```

So `execute()` is nothing but a wrapper for [PDOStatement::execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) which:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

If you get `1` when you cast it to string, it means everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per the tutorial execute function will only execute your sql query

you need to use this

```
public function resultset(){
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

which will return records from the database.